# Bootstrap 3 Modal in Rails 4 not displaying content with AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I've looked at quite a few posts on BS modals with AJAX, including this one: [Bootstrap Modal in Rails Keeps displaying the first record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24356517/bootstrap-modal-in-rails-keeps-displaying-the-first-record), but I am still having problems.

When using AJAX (JQuery 2.1.1), the modal opens, but the modal-body is empty.

I would like to: A) directly display an attribute (as was attempted with the code below) for demonstration purposes, and B) then display the show and edit views using partials.

Here is my code:

**/controllers/security_questions_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @security_questions = SecurityQuestion.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json
  end
end

def show 
  @security_question = SecurityQuestion.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json
  end
end
```

**/views/security_questions/index.html.erb**

```
<% @security_questions.each do |security_question| %>
. . .
  <td><%= link_to 'Show', security_question_path(security_question), data: {toggle: "modal", target: "#myModal"}, remote: true %></td>
. . .
<% end %>

. . .

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
. . .
      <div class="modal-body">   
      </div>
. . .
</div>
```

**/views/security_questions/show.js.erb**

```
$("#modal-body").html('<%= j(render @security_question.id) %>');
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

**firebug console shows the proper call when clicking to open the modal**

```
GET http://localhost/security_questions/3   200 OK 1.21s
. . .
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4">
  What is the name of your first pet?
  </div>
</div>
```

**no errors in log/development.log**

```
Started GET "/security_questions/3" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-27 10:44:13 -0800
Processing by SecurityQuestionsController#show as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"3"}
  SecurityQuestion Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `security_questions`.* FROM `security_questions` WHERE `security_questions`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1
  Rendered security_questions/show.html.erb within layouts/application (2.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (15.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_flash.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (2.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1164ms (Views: 1136.1ms | ActiveRecord: 1.9ms)
```

Comment: Try with format.js instead of format.json in response.

Answer (score 0):

You call

```
$("#modal-body").html('<%= j(render @security_question.id) %>');
```

But your modal-body is a class. Try...

```
$(".modal-body").html('<%= j(render @security_question.id) %>');
```

or change

```
<div class="modal-body"></div>
```

to

```
<div id="modal-body"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  You were right about the id (#) when I should have used the class (.).  I changed the js to ".modal-body", but it still is an empty modal.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I see you have a `show.js.erb` but not calling it from the controller. Can you try to put `format.js` in your show action within the respond_to?

Comment: like:
def show 
  @security_question = SecurityQuestion.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end

Comment: I made the recommended change, inserting format.js in the show action as suggested, but the modal is still empty.  Thanks for working on this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're trying to display the modal with both data attributes and the programmatic API, and I think you can't do both. Since the modal content is generated with an AJAX request, I would make this change:

BEFORE

```
  <td><%= link_to 'Show', security_question_path(security_question), data: {toggle: "modal", target: "#myModal"}, remote: true %></td>
```

AFTER

```
  <td><%= link_to 'Show', security_question_path(security_question), remote: true %></td>
```

Comment: I appreciate the reply.  I made the change and removed the data attributes as suggested.  The result was that the modal window did not even appear upon clicking the link.  Whereas before the modal would appear, but would be empty.

Comment: Any javascript error in the firebug console? If you inspect the HTML for the modal with firebug, has the modal-body been updated with the new HTML retrieved from the server?

Comment: The Console shows:
GET http://localhost/security_questions/5  200 OK 1.23s <div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4">
  What is your favorite movie?
  </div>
</div>

Comment: Yes, that seems to be OK. But is that code injected into the DOM? If you inspect the DOM with Firebug and look for the `<div id="#myModal" ...`, then click the link, does the HTML within the `<div class="modal-body"...` get updated? If so, could you please update the question without omitting any code for your `#myModal` div? The rest of the markup for the modal might not be OK.

Comment: It does not appear to be updating the HTML. In the HTML tab, I right-clicked on the <div class="modal-body"> and selected "Inspect in DOM Panel", which took me to the DOM tab with window > div.modal-body, at which point I began clicking the Show link, testing to see if the HTML was updated, both without the data attributes (and no modal opening) and with the data attributes (with an empty modal opening). (Is this the testing you were looking for?).  Thanks.