# Rails5: how to pass element to bs modal with form_tag

Tags: javascript, forms, bootstrap-modal, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an index view listing my elements. I want a button link to open a modal view containing a form_tag to pass some text which then get's sent to a third party API, but 'linked' to the element (it's ID) passed.

So far I get the modal showing and it's submitting correctly. But: the modal get's always the first/last element of the index list.

/config/routes.rb

```
namespace: manage do
  resources :elements do
    member do
      post :my_action
    end
  end
end
```

/manage/elements/index.html.haml

```
@elements.each do |element|
  %tr
    %td
      = link_to 'btn-text', '#myModal', data: { toggle: 'modal', target: '#myModal'}
    = render 'manage/elements/element_modal', element: element
```

/manage/elements/_element_modal.html.haml

```
#myModal.modal.fade{...}
  .modal-dialog
    .modal-content
      = form_tag path_to_my_action(element), method: :post do
        = text_field_tag :text, params[:text]
        = submit_tag
```

I tried different approaches (a modal for each element, data-attributes, AJAX) like found eg here: [Bootstrap Modal in Rails Keeps displaying the first record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24356517/bootstrap-modal-in-rails-keeps-displaying-the-first-record)

But actually I can't get any of these working and I don't get why. Can you give me a hint based on above example so I finally get this working? Thanks!